# jquery script for video start after page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

i got a question if in jquery exists some event which allow me to play video instantly after my website is loaded. For now i using mousemove event, which works fine for now, but if i want add another layer on my website over my video content, it should not work.

```
$(function(){ 
var video = document.querySelector('#video1'); 
if(video){
video.addEventListener('mousemove',function(){ video.play(); },false)
}; 
});
```

Comment: Why not just add `autoplay` to your video?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you simply start the video when jQuery document ready function is fired?

```
$(function(){ 
    var video = document.querySelector('#video1');
    video.play();
});
```

At least that seems to work in this small [Codepen](http://codepen.io/ckuijjer/pen/NPxdRp) I created from the [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) HTML5 video example.

Comment: And did you try setting the `autoplay="true"` attribute?

Comment: i tried that but autoplay attribute is ignored in chrome and have no clue why but it works in other browsers even in IE

Comment: Works in Chrome in http://codepen.io/ckuijjer/pen/dPGNRb. I'm afraid I'm out of ideas, sorry mate!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the `<video>` element, you can just add the `autoplay` attribute:

```
<video autoplay>
    <source src=""/>
</video>
```

Comment: yeah i use video tag element, problem is and i dont know why but autoplay attribute is ignored in chrome but it works in other browsers even in IE...